# Prefix all variable names in R

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, prefix

I want to prefix all variable names in a data frame with `b_`.

Any ideas how to do this I can't find any similar questions or advice out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
colnames(df) <- paste0("b_",colnames(df))
```